# Disconnect event gets fired 2 minutes later

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using Node.JS and Socket.IO to create a chat, I use XHR polling with a duration of 10 to host it on Heroku.

When I leave the page with my client, I'd like to calll the disconnect method automatically on the server which removes it from other clients. It's in fact done but... 2 minutes after the client has really left the page, which is quite awkward.

Is there a way to call the disconnect method as soon as the client doesn't reply ? Or at least being a little faster to know when the client is not there anymore ?

I've tried to close the socket client-side on page exit with jQuery but it doesn't work. The problem is that using `socket.disconnect()` is asynchronous and non-blocking and the user leaves before the request is completed...

Comment: Good question, hope it is solved ASAP. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with `heartbeat timeout`, `heartbeat interval` and `close timeout` values of `socket.io` configuration.

Search for `heartbeat` and `timeout` in this page: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

Comment: `io.set("heartbeat timeout", 10);` and `io.set("heartbeat interval", 5);` don't seem to change anything at all... That's weird.

Comment: I downgraded socket.io to version 0.9.4 because it was a bug though it still doesn't work on my web host. Finally gave you the points because  you were the only who tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `'sync disconnect on unload'` option on the socket.io client to true, it will send a synchronous xhr disconnect request in onbeforeunload that will disconnect the socket.